Importing video games into the EU
So I’m moving Back to the EU in July, from the US where I’ve been living for seven years. I have a lot of video games that I would like to bring with me. Considering that I own multiple game systems, how do I get through security efficiently, and do I have to pay an import tax? Would this even be legal, since I have loads of controllers and games that might frustrate security?
In case it’s relevant, I’m moving to Sweden

Household effects and moving are treated differently than ‘importing’ usually. When I moved from the Netherlands back to the US after a few years there was no import duty on the stuff I shipped back.

I don't know how it works with EU but in most American countries you would be tax exempt when moving back home after a few years. Some countries would accept your previous residence permit as proof, others require a certificate from the local consulate (Swedish consulate in US for your case). Maybe you can call your consulate and ask.

More about import tax exemptions: https://www.tullverket.se/en/startpage/private/moving/movingtoandfromsweden/movingtoswedenfromacountryoutsidetheeu.4.311bf4f016e69d6ea0d760.html
